# Android Signed APK not showing Googlemap

Tags: android

I am implemented Google map in my application it's showing Google map on device before creating signed apk. When i created signed apk then it's not showing Google map on device so I am not getting what I did wrong so any one can give me suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any additional information to go on, I'm going to assume you created the release APK still using the debug Google Maps API key.  You will need to use create a API key for the release APK.  See: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint

If its something else, could you add logcat output to your original post?