# The map is not visible in the distributed/published app, but works fine in the development version

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I used google map api in my application in android. It works fine with api key in development version but the same does not shows the map view in the published version. Just grids are displaying. Can anyone help me regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the debug keystore key in the published version that is why its not showing map. You have created the keystore for your published version right? You need to get the Google Maps API key for that keystore (by providing the SHA/MD 5 key). After that map will be shown to the published version as well.

Comment: Thank you :)  You are right. I am using the debug keystore key in the published version. I am a beginner in android. Could you please send me any tutorial link on how to get the Google Maps API key for the published version keystore (by providing the SHA/MD 5 key).

Comment: You don't need any tutorial link. You need to do the same thing which you have did for getting key with debug.keystore. But for published version you need to use your keystore. Use the same command but instead of debug.keystore use your keystore file for e.g. your_app.keystore

Comment: Hi Scorpion Thanks :)  I got the Google Maps v2 API key for the release_keystore of my published version (by providing the SHA key). How can I replace that api key in already exported apk file. Whether I need to replace the generated new api key instead of old api key in the debug version and once again export the apk using the existing keystore? or what else I want to do?

Comment: I replaced the generated new api key instead of old api key in the debug version and once again export the apk using the existing keystore (ie.) release_keystore but the map does not shown when installing the generated apk file. What to do?

Comment: Then you are doing some mistake. Without seeing your code can't help you.

Comment: 1)created new_keystore file and exported new_apk file 
2)got the SHA key for new_keystore file 
3)used that SHA key for getting the new map api key 
4)where to replace that api key? 
5)what to do further? 
I also installed google play service in sdk manager. 
My xml coding is : 
<com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:apiKey="AIzaSyDhvY2g94y-o8Xn1fcibBgNPADNoy_wtdo" android:clickable="true" />

Comment: You got the new apiKey right. you need to replace it with that new key within this xml coding. And then clean and run your android app again, check that you are getting the map. After that you need to export the apk file not before otherwise it will never show the map in apk. First test everything with emulator/device without exporting it. If it works then and then only export it. Did you tested it in your device or emulator?

Comment: Thank You Very Much Scorpion :) Finally it works when creating a new api key using MD 5 fingerprint in Google Maps Android API v1 but I dont know why it was not showing when I generate a api key using SHA in Google Maps Android API v2 (or) v3!

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to generate a signed apk see below link

[Android Signed APK not showing Googlemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877312/android-signed-apk-not-showing-googlemap)